# ASP.NET MVC - triggering the stored procedure which runs for 5 minutes - call it asynchronusly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. I have a situation like a user clicks "Send" button -> then the controller will execute a stored procedure (which is taking more than 5 minutes to complete which I can't avoid).

Using the stored procedures results I am sending few emails.

Now we want user experience should be like: users hits "Send" button -> UI will show a message "We are processing your request and you will receive emails shortly" -> user continues to do his work or even he may close the browser too. In the background, the code should execute the stored procedure and send email to users.

Our only question here is, what is the best way to execute the stored procedure in the background without blocking the user?

Comment: Use some batch process in background which can execute Stored Procedure and send email. Using monolithic application will stop processing if user close browser or navigates to other page. Based on some database flag, the batch can execute stored proc and send emails.

Comment: i think you first want to look at ajax, <------- really then in that call which is just a background web request.... which would now take 5min, not ideal for feeding back to user so, then in that you want to off load the work, this can be done with something as simple as not awaiting the result, i think u gona get confused with what im saying so first step get the click to be an ajax request. then come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to execute it in a non-blocking way is to execute it in an asynchronous way. Running the stored procedure execution method and processing the request message concurrently. This allows your UI to be more responsive to user actions while running these methods.